# Twitter integration with parse in iOS getting error 1012

Tags: ios, twitter, ios7, parse-platform

I have been fighting this for some time, and not able to narrow down the problem. I am using parse twitter integration, but get the following error (I have already checked all the topics regarding the following error message):

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"
>    UserInfo=0x98ead30 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token,
>    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, NSUnderlyingError=0x98cd1c0 
>   "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}

I have specified a callback url for my app in the twitter settings, and set read & write permission for the application (checked the allow twitter sign in option as well). I have tested the https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token from the simulator and can open it (taught it is a network issue at first). I am testing parse and this is a bit of show stopper for me. Here is my code:

in didFinishWithOptions:

> [PFTwitterUtils initializeWithConsumerKey:@"appkey"
>                                  consumerSecret:@"appsecret"];

and my twitter button action:

> [PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
>
> NSLog(@"%@",error);
>
> if (!user) {
>
> ```
> NSLog(@"%@", user);
>
> NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
>
> return;
> ```
>
> } else if (user.isNew) {
>
> ```
> NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in with Twitter!");
> ```
>
> } else {
>
> ```
> NSLog(@"User logged in with Twitter!");
> ```
>
> }
>
> }];

I am using the latest version of the SDK. Does anyone have any idea what might be the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: hey any idea about how to save user profile details to profile to user table in parse?? please help me if you can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had recently worked with twitter integration into parse.com, first you need to set up twitter app on devs.twitter.com then copy the consumer keys into parse.com> your app> settings > user authentication , make sure to enable twitter authorisation(which is enabled by default). While initialising PFTwitter utils make sure to pass you twitter app key and consumer secret ,and this allows you to use twitter login/signup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for some reason after turning this option to off and then on and the app magically started working.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. The first time i launch my app i can not get passed the "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)", yet the second time it works...not sure

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that within the developer area for your application on Twitter, under the Settings tab, that you have specified a Callback URL. Even if you are not using this field, Parse requires the usage of it because their codebase still contains code related to Twitter OAuth 1.0a. Fill in anything you'd like in order to make it work.

Comment: This worked for me. I had left the callback url blank and as soon as I filled it in I stopped getting the 1012 errors.